# CMakeLists creating an utility library

Tags: c, cmake, static-libraries

I'm learning how to use `CMake` to create a static libraries and share them the other modules in a project. The structure of the project is the following:

```
  root
    |
    |__ util
    |     |
    |     |__ CMakeLists.txt
    |
    |__ execution
    |     |
    |     |__ CMakeLists.txt
    |
    |__ logic
    |     |
    |     |__ CMakeLists.txt
    |
CMakeLists.txt
```

So I have a `util` module which contains some utility structures and function which are supposed to be used by the other modules (`execution`, `logic`). I have 2 misunderstandings:

I. Is it appropriate to simply add the headers of the `util` modules to the include path in the `root/CMakeLists.txt` and then link the `util` statically? Currently the `util/CMakeLists.txt` is the following:

```
add_library(util src/util.c)
```

II. In case the `util` library contains no source file and just common data-structures and definitions used by the other modules how can we add it? I tried to write `util/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_library(util)
```

and then in the `root/CMakeLists.txt`

```
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/util/include")
add_subdirectory(util)
```

But it didn't work.

```
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library util without any source files. 
This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
```

Comment: "Is it appropriate ..." - Why do not try that? (Yes, this should work). The second question is unrelated to the first one. (Please, ask about single problem in a question post!). The library without source file is known as "*header-only* library". CMake supports creating such sort of libraries, just google for that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks. I simply was not aware of the concept of "header-only library"